# Call recording problem

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, apk, call-recording

I use a Samsungs Galaxy Star Pro GT-S7262 with Jelly Bean 4.1.2. I have installed quite a few call recorder apps from Google Play and though they are recording all the calls, whenever I play back the recordings it sounds like everything has been recorded in fast forward mode (or is playing as such).
It is happening with all the call recorder apps I have installed. What could be the problem and how can I resolve it as everything sounds jumbled and indecipherable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some phones just can't support call recording because of how the hardware is designed. If you've tried several apps, and none of them work correctly, that is probably the case here.

Comment: While one should not expect audio recording to work, in this case it sounds like it basically is working, as the reported problem is quite minor and easily corrected.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem and also installed many callrecoders, but all gave the same problem. I downloaded the audio files from my phone and loaded them into a sound editor (i.e. sony soundforge). I played the file 5.5 times slower and noticed that they played well, I could understand the conversation perfectly. 
So it seems that all is recorded only played back 5.5 times too fast. This is a problem which can not be corrected within the phone.
My advice: download all audio files to a computer, convert and save them with the new speed. They will work fine!

Comment: Good investigation, however it's unclear why you believe this cannot be corrected within the phone.  It would be trivial to write an audio player which makes the same change.  Likely, what is actually happening is a confusion between 8 KSPS and 44.1 KSPS (your ~5.5 ratio) and all that needs to happen is to change the sample rate field in the files.

Comment: What I meant was that I have not come across any call recorder software or any option within the android OS to adjust the sample rate so far. 
Looks like a business opportunity for an app developer!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that on my Samsumg GT-S5282, call recording apps will always record my files exactly 83.097% faster than the files should be.

As a workaround, I use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) on my PC to normalize the audio after recording. I change the Audio Speed by -83.097% and then change the Pitch by -4%, then export it as a .wav file. This fixes the audio so that it will sound normal when played back.